# Вычленить все 11-значные числа из строки

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Есть большая строка (порядка 40 тыс. симвлов). Нужно найти в ней все 11-значные числа и записать в массив. Как это сделать на PHP? Помогите, пожалуйста, т.к. в регулярках не разбираюсь совершенно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~(?<!\d)\d{11}(?!=\d)~', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Почти все работает! Не могу только почему то вывести содержимое массива и обращаться к его элементам, почему?   for ($i = 0; $i < count($ddd); $i++) echo $ddd[$i]." ";

Comment: Наверное, потому что обращаетесь не к нужному элементу массива,
пробуйте так:

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) { echo $matches[0][$i]." ";}